# Kendo UI DropDownList control

Tags: user-interface, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am using selenium2 and webdriver to automate a Kendo UI and I am unable to control the dropdown to select a model value form the dropdown list. How can I select a value from a Kendo UI DropDownList using webdriver commands?

Answer (score 0):

The issues that it is not coded as a Select element:

```
<div class="FormLabel">Select Model(s):</div>
<div class="FormInput FixMultiSelect">
<div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header" unselectable="on" style="">
<div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap" unselectable="on">
<ul id="ModelList_taglist" class="k-reset" unselectable="on" role="listbox"></ul>
<input class="k-input" style="width: 25px;" accesskey="" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="ModelList_taglist ModelList_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
<span class="k-icon k-loading k-loading-hidden"></span>
</div>
<select id="ModelList" data-placeholder="Click Here" multiple="multiple" data-role="multiselect" style="display: none;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<option value="3">ABCGateway_Model</option>
<option value="25">Jack_Gateway_Model</option>
<option value="4">CC Model_1</option>
<option value="26">Sam_Model_1</option>
</select>
<span style="font-family: 'MyriadPro-Regular',Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none; line-height: 16px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

`Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")));`

Once this is done you can select the required value in 3 ways. Consider an HTML file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>
</select>
<body>
</html>
```

Now to identify dropdown do

`Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));`

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do

`dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");`

or

`dropdown.selectByIndex(1);`

or

`dropdown.selectByValue("prog");`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Kendo does not generate option tags.

Comment: and how am i supposed to know that ??